# Possible to disable CMS's conflicting native JavaScript onSubmit scripting?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blackbaud

I am building a very simple 5 question multiple choice quiz "game" that just asks 5 simple questions displayed using HTML radio buttons, and a JavaScript function that validates if the user's selection is correct, and iterates a "score" which, when the submit button is clicked, displays "You got X out of X correct." Basically a .js 101 project.

I'm using a Content Management System called Blackbaud Internet Solutions (BBIS). It is proprietary to Blackbaud, and allows the user to build a fully functioning website that integrated with Blackbaud's CRM database. It allows you to build layout using HTML, however in the built-in HTML editor you do not declare any !DOCTYPE or <body> or <head> tags, you just start with your first  or whatever, and the system will build out each page using it's native .aspx functionality.
BBIS does have a sophisticated stylesheet section that allows you to create and stack .css, however JavaScript is not handled in the same way.

A web developer that wants to include JavaScript on a page must insert that script by creating what BBIS calls an "Unformatted Text Part." (a "part" is like a widget, or block etc.) The Unformatted Text Part allows you to insert whatever you have between <script> ... and ...</script> in the:

- <head>
- <body>
- at the end of the <body>

Locally on my workstation the .html, .css, and .js files all work together perfectly. And in BBIS, the HTML renders great, the CSS looks good, however, the JavaScript aspect just doesn't work at all. When you click the submit button, the screen flashes and the form's 5 radio buttons just reset to unselected.

Using Chrome's developer tools I can see in the DOM that the CMS (BBIS) brings a whole lot of unnecessary JavaScript to the party. I'm sure that on a page with more elements, these scripts have a perfectly logical function. But this page is literally a white background with nothing but a quiz in the middle of the page. My onSubmit button function has 3-4 other "onSubmit" scripts running on the same page, and I cannot help but think that this is the problem.

In the DOM, I can see that my JavaScript function has been inserted into the <head> tag, because that is where I configured it to load inside of the BBIS "unformatted text part". All the native BBIS "onSubmit scripts" appear in the <body>. Is there a way that I can insert some JavaScript into the <head> that will "take out" those <body> BBIS "onSubmit" scripts?

Answer (score 0):

when you get a blank page maybe you leave the CMS page on submit?
How does your html form look like?
Another thing is, are you using jquery? Most CMS bring their own version of jquery. Try to use jquery in no conflict mode https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Please ask clarification questions in comments, not in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the unformatted text part, and select the 'advanced options' button.  You can choose to drop your part in the `<head>` from there.